# How to merge custom code with drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to add jquery slider code to my drupal site, in one of the block in my site.

But i am not able to add my code to drupal site & get it working.

How can i add the custom code to drupal site.

How can i solve this?

Code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".featured1").slideUp(7000);
});
</script>

<div class="featured1"><img src="images/2.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create js file in your `theme_folder/js`, e.g, scripts.js, put your code into that file, open .info file of theme and add `scripts[]=js/scripts.js` OR
2. Create a js file as I wrote above and open template.php of your theme and put

   ```
   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME_NAME') . '/js/scripts.js', array('type' => 'file', 'group' => JS_THEME));
   ```

   in `YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page()`.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid adding JS in your blocks. Use a file in your theme (like `/sites/all/themes/your_theme/js/my_scripts.js`). Many Drupal themes include a `script.js`, using Drupal JS behaviors (like Zen). You can also add your own custom JS file modifying the `your_theme.info` file (you'll find examples all around).

If you really want to add JS in a block, you may run into JS aliases problem, replacing `$` by `jQuery` can help. But, really, don't do that, it's gonna be a mess to maintain :)....